# Difference between Angularjs and angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-cli

What is the Difference between Angularjs and angular(eg. cli and versions)?
I want to work Angular but I don't know differences for select one of them. I googled but don't explicitly mention differences between them.

Comment: AngularJS: a different framework, which is the ancestor of Angular. Angular CLI: a tool allowing to create, maintain, build, test, run Angular projects.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**AngularJS** is the first version of **Angular**.
**AngularCLI** is a tool used to generate angular components, They are not comparable.

What you might mean, is what is the difference between **Angular** and **AngularJS**.

The answer to this question is that **AngularJS** is the first version of **Angular**.
It works with javascript and it is still getting supported but it *is not compatible* with **Angular**.
I'd suggest you start with **Angular** (Can also be called Angular2 or Angular4).

It is very confusing, but to sum it up, **AngularJS** is an old version.
**Angular** is the newer version and since everyone is migrating to **Angular**.
I would suggest you *learn **Angular** instead of **AngularJS***.

Answer (score 6):

AngularJS typically refers to Angular 1, or the original angular which has some differences between Angular 2+.
Some of the logic and keywords are different from 1 to 2+.

Angular CLI is a command-line interface for the current version of Angular, Angular 4.

Angular CLI provides a generator/framework for a new project using Angular.
The current documentation on [angular.io](https://angular.io/) is in Angular CLI.

Answer (score 5):

**`Angular CLI`** stands for **`Angular Command Line Interface`**. As the name says, it is a command line tool for creating angular apps. It is recommended to use angular cli for creating angular apps as you don't need to spend time installing and configuring all the required dependencies and wiring everything together.

angular-cli provides you with boilerplates and therefore, saves your time.

whereas  AngularJS is a client side framework of JavaScript which is based on MVC Architecture and provides a Single-page application solution for dynamic websites.

If you want choose any technology then following points should be considered:

- Code Re-usability
- Maintenance of the existing code
- Testing of the code
- Modularity and Scalibility for Team Development