# Angular 2+ -- ng-repeat doesn't seem to work, but {{ var }} does

Tags: angular

I'm trying to loop through a JSON object using `ng-repeat`, using [this](https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.5/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) as reference.  What I currently have is:

```
<mat-card-content>
  <p>{{ selected.items }}</p>
  <p>{{ selected.items["0aa60412-a62b-4967-8c9e-b12764df6a9d"].itemName }}</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in selected.items">{{ item.itemName }}</li>
  </ul>
</mat-card-content>
```

where the 2nd `<p>` uses a hardcoded ID of the first entry being returned

The `<p>` tags work, but the `<li>` does not, it just has a single bullet with no content in it (where the object has 16 items).  The console gives the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemName' of undefined`.

The JSON object is formatted like so:

```
{
  "0aa60412-a62b-4967-8c9e-b12764df6a9d": { itemName: "value", [...] },
  [...]
}
```

Other attempts which also failed include:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in selected.items">{{ key }}</li>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-to-iterate-over-the-keys-and-values-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs

Comment: @FrankModica Tried the answer for that question, didn't work.  Should have mentioned that I tried all the methods in the ngRepeat reference material linked in the question.

Comment: Not even if you do `{{ value.itemName }}`?

Comment: @FrankModica Correct.  Seeing [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-to-iterate-over-the-keys-and-values-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs#comment33941787_15127934) I might just re-work this to be an array and figure out a different way to loop over it.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Blackhole This was a problem with my lack of experience with Angular.  I've posted an answer to hopefully help others that fall into the same confusions.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with my being new to Angular.  Basically, [`ngRepeat`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.5/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) is [not recommended for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127834/how-to-iterate-over-the-keys-and-values-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs#comment33941787_15127934).  Also, `ng-repeat` a feature of AngularJS but not Angular, which are apparently [different things](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46891098/1618257).  With that out of the way, onto the solution.

Since you cannot use `ng-repeat`, the alternative is to change your object to an array and use [`*ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) like so:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of selected.items">{{ item.itemName }}</li>
```

For converting from object to array, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41458579/1618257):

```
return Object.keys(retItems).map(function(idx) {
  return retItems[idx];
});
```